# Finding two hidden words

Tags: word

Two words are hidden in these strange lines. Can you find them, knowing that they are somewhat related?

> 19x26 = 4594 YEAH
>
> 25x25 = 6925 PACE
>
> 3x92 $\vphantom{}$ $\vphantom{}$ = 2786 WATT
>
> 21x12 = 2526 LOAD
>
> 42x8 $\vphantom{}$ $\vphantom{}$ = 3363 JIFF
>
> 13x9 $\vphantom{}$ $\vphantom{}$ = 3117 HELP
>
> 51x13 = 6632 MEME
>
> 4x80 $\vphantom{}$ $\vphantom{}$ = 9320 NOOB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the letters found by others are correct, I think the somewhat related words are:

> HAND and FEET

Comment: I'm missing something obviously. I'm trying to stop myself from submitting all the 2, 4 letter words I find

Comment: And that's correct! They are indeed related, aren't they :)?

Comment: @IAmInPLS  I get it now

Answer (score 2):

So I found two words.

> death fen

You can find them if you

> take from each line the letter on the position where is the extra number in the result of the calculation (42x8 = 336 - so take the fourth letter).

The letters are

> eatdfhen

But I am not sure if this is the correct approach :-).

Comment: Your reasoning is correct but these are not the two words I am looking for, although your letters are the good ones. Read carefully the riddle again :)

Answer (score 2):

Same letter as Artholl could give :

> hate fend

Comment: Same advice : read the riddle again, carefully...